# Flutter perfect message when snapshot.data doesn't have data in Future

Tags: flutter

in this below code i try to show `list is empty` message when `snapshot.hasData` is false

```
body: FutureBuilder(
  future: Provider.of<TicketRepliesTableDao>(context).find(ticketId: _ticket.id),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final List<TicketRepliesTableData> ticketReplies = snapshot.data;
        if (ticketReplies.isNotEmpty) {

        }
      } else {
        return _loader(message: 'list is empty');
      }
    } else
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

but in that i have `CircularProgressIndicator()` always, in view,even it doesn't have any data and `ticketReplies` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `builder`, with this logic.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // show your data
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    } else {
      // show list is empty
      return Text("List is empty");
    }
  }
  // by default show loading bar
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: i get the same behavior

Comment: I've updated the code with a sample, please run it and let me know if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: you right, i think `future` for getting data from database, that have different behavior

Comment: @DolDurma are you sure you're returning `null` when there is no data?

Comment: you right, my code doesn't return `null` and that have problem. up until this point, i didn't know my code doesn't return `null` thank you very very much